# Inheritance :hidden variable of superclass in subclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Consider the following code :

```
class B
{
     int j=15;
}

public class A extends B
{
  int j=10;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      A obj =new A();
      System.out.println(obj.j);   // i now want to print j of class B which is hidden,how?
  }

}
```

How should i reveal the hidden variable of a super class in subclass ?

Comment: Consider this to be an awful practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access to it, using `super`:

```
System.out.println(super.j);
```

but you can use `super` inside the class `A`, so you can do something like this:

```
public class A extends B
{
    int j = 10;

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(super.j);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A obj = new A();
        System.out.println(obj.j); // 10
        obj.print(); // 15
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get to it from A class using super. You need to create a method for this. Example:

```
class A extends B
{
    int j=10;

    int getSuperJ() {
        return super.j;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A obj =new A();
        System.out.println(obj.j);   //10
        System.out.println(obj.getSuperJ());  //15
    }

}
```